# Perlin Noise function - values way out of range

Tags: c, opengl, noise, perlin-noise

So, I've been trying to use Perlin Noise in my project, and bizarrely the noise function outputs mostly values way out of the [-1, 1] bounds. I've implemented it in C through [Perlin's code for his improved noise in Java](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/), and [another useful implementation in C++ by sol](https://github.com/sol-prog/Perlin_Noise). I've ran through it at least 20 times and made sure it was exactly the same, but couldn't find any causes for the issue.
Here is how it looks:

```
//   DEFAULT_PERMUTATION is defined through the preprocessor.
// It is basically an initializer of the same array used in Perlin's
// implementation, except it has been duplicated into a 512 element array


double simpleNoise(double x, double y, double z){

double res;

int p[512] = DEFAULT_PERMUTATION;

int X = (int) floor(x) & 255;
int Y = (int) floor(y) & 255;
int Z = (int) floor(z) & 255;

double u = fade(x);
double v = fade(y);
double w = fade(z);

int A = p[X] + Y;
int AA = p[A] + Z;
int AB = p[A + 1] + Z;
int B = p[X + 1] + Y;
int BA = p[B] + Z;
int BB = p[B + 1] + Z;

x -= floor(x);
y -= floor(y);
z -= floor(z);


res = lerp(w, lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA  ], x  , y  , z   ),  
                                 grad(p[BA  ], x-1, y  , z   )), 
                         lerp(u, grad(p[AB  ], x  , y-1, z   ),  
                                 grad(p[BB  ], x-1, y-1, z   ))),
                 lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA+1], x  , y  , z-1 ),  
                                 grad(p[BA+1], x-1, y  , z-1 )), 
                         lerp(u, grad(p[AB+1], x  , y-1, z-1 ),
                                 grad(p[BB+1], x-1, y-1, z-1 ))));
return res;
}
```

The other private functions are pretty straightfoward too:

```
double fade(double t){
return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10);
}

double lerp(double t, double a, double b){
return a + t * (b - a); 
}

double grad(int hash, double x, double y, double z){
int h = hash & 15;                     
  double u = h<8 ? x : y,                 
         v = h<4 ? y : h==12||h==14 ? x : z;
  return ((h&1) == 0 ? u : -u) + ((h&2) == 0 ? v : -v);
}
```

[In my project, the noise looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMmA9.png), due to the fact that the color only cares about values between 0 and 1, but tests with some positions give absurd values like -15, 32, some bigger than thousands. Feeding the values (1,-4,1), (2,5,1), (2,0,0) are interesting to say the least.

What could the problem be?

EDIT: For investigation purposes, this program lists inconsistencies found:

```
#define DEFAULT_PERMUTATION { \
    151,160,137,91,90,15,131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142, \
    8,99,37,240,21,10,23,190, 6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117, \
    35,11,32,57,177,33,88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168, 68,175,74,165,71, \
    134,139,48,27,166,77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41, \
    55,46,245,40,244,102,143,54, 65,25,63,161,1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208, 89, \
    18,169,200,196,135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186, 3,64,52,217,226, \
    250,124,123,5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182, \
    189,28,42,223,183,170,213,119,248,152, 2,44,154,163, 70,221,153,101,155,167,  \
    43,172,9,129,22,39,253, 19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185, 112,104,218,246, \
    97,228,251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241, 81,51,145,235,249,14,239, \
    107,49,192,214, 31,181,199,106,157,184, 84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127, 4,150,254, \
    138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180,\
    151,160,137,91,90,15,131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142, \
    8,99,37,240,21,10,23,190, 6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117, \
    35,11,32,57,177,33,88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168, 68,175,74,165,71, \
    134,139,48,27,166,77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41, \
    55,46,245,40,244,102,143,54, 65,25,63,161,1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208, 89, \
    18,169,200,196,135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186, 3,64,52,217,226, \
    250,124,123,5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182, \
    189,28,42,223,183,170,213,119,248,152, 2,44,154,163, 70,221,153,101,155,167,  \
    43,172,9,129,22,39,253, 19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185, 112,104,218,246, \
    97,228,251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241, 81,51,145,235,249,14,239, \
    107,49,192,214, 31,181,199,106,157,184, 84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127, 4,150,254, \
    138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180 }
#define SIZE 10
double fade(double t){
return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10);
}

double lerp(double t, double a, double b){
return a + t * (b - a); 
}

double grad(int hash, double x, double y, double z){
int h = hash & 15;                     
double u = h<8 ? x : y,                 
     v = h<4 ? y : h==12||h==14 ? x : z;
return ((h&1) == 0 ? u : -u) + ((h&2) == 0 ? v : -v);
}
double simpleNoise(double x, double y, double z){
double res;
int p[512] = DEFAULT_PERMUTATION;
int X = (int) floor(x) & 255;
int Y = (int) floor(y) & 255;
int Z = (int) floor(z) & 255;
double u = fade(x);
double v = fade(y);
double w = fade(z);
int A = p[X] + Y;
int AA = p[A] + Z;
int AB = p[A + 1] + Z;
int B = p[X + 1] + Y;
int BA = p[B] + Z;
int BB = p[B + 1] + Z;
x -= floor(x);
y -= floor(y);
z -= floor(z);
res = lerp(w, lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA  ], x  , y  , z   ),  
                             grad(p[BA  ], x-1, y  , z   )), 
                     lerp(u, grad(p[AB  ], x  , y-1, z   ),  
                             grad(p[BB  ], x-1, y-1, z   ))),
             lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA+1], x  , y  , z-1 ),  
                             grad(p[BA+1], x-1, y  , z-1 )), 
                     lerp(u, grad(p[AB+1], x  , y-1, z-1 ),
                             grad(p[BB+1], x-1, y-1, z-1 ))));
return res;
}
main(){
int i, j, k, n=0;
double e;
for(i=-SIZE/2; i<SIZE/2; i++){
    for(j=-SIZE/2; j<SIZE/2; j++){
        for(k=-SIZE/2; k<SIZE/2; k++){
            e = simpleNoise(i, j, k);
            if(fabs(e) > 1){
               printf("P(%d,%d,%d): %f\n", i, j, k, e);
               n++;
            }
        }
    }
}
printf("%d inconsistencies found", n);
}
```

Comment: I think we need to have a [mcve] for this, as it does not run as shown and we need to inspect the results of your function.

Comment: added a code that can test the function for points in a box of side 10. out of 1000 points, 966 are absurd.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Please post a [mcve]  so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks ( for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: parameter and variable names should indicate `content` or `usage`  (or better, both).  names like 't', 'a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'h', 'u', 'v', 'p', 'BA', 'AA', 'BB', 'AB', etc are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: regarding: `int p[512] = DEFAULT_PERMUTATION;`  what is `DEFAULT_PERMUTATION`?  what are you expecting to be the contents of the array `p[256]` after this statement?

Answer (score 3):

The reference implementation [here](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/) does

```
x -= floor(x);
y -= floor(y);
z -= floor(z);
```

*before* such steps as

```
double u = fade(x);
double v = fade(y);
double w = fade(z);
```

Your implementation moved that step much further down the code. Why?

If you move it back to its original location, in your "investigation" code the noise function will always expectedly return zero, since Perlin noise function is supposed to return zero at integer points.

Comment: Yeah, I did this for some reason and missed how other variables needed the altered value. Don't know how. Thanks